# How to directly print last error code, text in C

Tags: c

To print the last error code in C I can do:

```
#include <errno.h>
printf("%d\n", errno);     // errno is global, nothing else needed
```

How would I directly print the mapped error message without using `perror`? The internal function it uses is:

```
char buf[1024];
errstring = __strerror_r (errnum, buf, sizeof buf);
```

But I'm having a hard time importing the `__` method. Is there a more direct way to do that, given the errno?

Comment: A quick search should have told you about [`strerror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror).

Comment: Can you explain how you got from the particular problem you're trying to solve, to the implementation of `perror`? Because that is the real problem you need you fix. `errno` has its own manual page, pointing out `strerror`. Work on your analysis and troubleshooting skills instead of diving onto Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strerror`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) from `string.h`:

```
#include <string.h>

char buf[1024];
strcpy(buf, strerror(errno));
printf("%d --> %s\n", errno, buf);
```

> 14 --> Bad address